# Laravel 5.7 - localization

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization

I followed [this link](https://medium.com/@serhii.matrunchyk/using-laravel-localization-with-javascript-and-vuejs-23064d0c210e) and make localization works in my `vue` file.

However, when I create a new file:

```
resources/lang/en/users.php:

<?php

return [
    'user' => 'User Management',
];
```

then call `{{ trans('users.user') }}` in my template, nothing happen.

I tried:
    resources/lang/en/auth.php:

```
    return [
    'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    'test' => 'test records',///<-- my test!!!
    'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',
    ];
```

then call `{{ trans('auth.test') }}` in my template, also not working.

It seems like I am still missing out some parts for localization.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After much of testing, it turn out to be the cache issue.
In blade, there is no issue. But in `vue`, it seems like it is getting the data from the cache.

So, every time after adding new file or array, run this code:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and refresh your `vue`, then it works.